# 3D matrix Indexing using 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

Could anyone shed some light on how this `for` loop can be replaced by a single command in MATLAB?

```
for i  = 1 : size(w,3)
    x=w(:,:,i);
    w1(i,:)=x(B(i),:); 
end
clear x
```

Here, `w` is a 3D (`x by y by z`) matrix and B (`1 by z`) is a vector containing rows pertaining to each layer in `w`. This `for` loop takes about 150 seconds to execute when w is `500000` layers deep. I tried using,

```
Q = w(B,:,:);
Q = reshape(Q(1,:),[500000,2])';
```

This creates a matrix `Q` of size `500000 X 2 X 500000` and MATLAB threw me an error saying memory out of bound. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating intermediate variables (such as `x`) and using a for loop. The core idea of the following approach is to first pre-populate the indices used and then use linear indexing to access all the elements at once. Then, we can reshape to get the desired result.

```
ind = [B(1)*ones(size(w,2),1) (1:size(w,2)).' 1*ones(size(w,2),1)];
ind = [ind; [B(2)*ones(size(w,2),1) (1:size(w,2)).' 2*ones(size(w,2),1)]];
ind = [ind; [B(3)*ones(size(w,2),1) (1:size(w,2)).' 3*ones(size(w,2),1)]];
lin_ind = sub2ind(size(w), ind(:,1), ind(:,2), ind(:,3));
w1 = reshape(w(lin_ind),size(w,2),size(w,3)).'
```

On my system, this matches with `w1` computed with the loop given in your question. Note that you may need to use a for loop to pre-populate the indices. I wrote three expressions since I was experimenting with small matrices. Actually, the first three lines can be written in such a way that you don't need loops at all and it still works with any size. I will leave that up to you.